# wpf processing data before binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I have a canvas that shows an audio waveform, which is made using a lot of Lines. Each line is Tagged with it's time code so I can identify where in the audio it is.

I want to put a rectangle on the canvas based on data stored in an observable collection.
Basically, Timespan start and end points so I can show a block of audio.

The problem I'm having is that to show the rectangle, I have to know the Canvas left value and width.
I can get these by scanning through the canvas children until I find the correct line and getting its X1 value, but I don't know how to do it in a binding.

I want to bind the observable collection ItemsControl so I can show the rectangles on the canvas.

Is it possible to bind to a function or something that would do the calculations based on the data in the observable collection?

XAML:

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <Canvas Name="waveform" >
            <ItemsControl Name="RectArea"> <!-- Where I hope to have the rectangles appear on top of the waveform canvas -->
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Stroke="Yellow" Fill="Yellow" Opacity="0.2" Height="200" Width="{Binding Width}" Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Creating the waveform:

```
        Dim seconds As Integer = 0
        lines = New Dictionary(Of String, Line)

        Using Reader As New AudioFileReader(openfile.FileName)
            Dim samples = Reader.Length / (Reader.WaveFormat.Channels * Reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8)
            Dim f = 0.0F
            Dim max = 0.0F

            Dim batch As Integer = Math.Max(10, samples / samplecount)
            Dim mid = 100
            Dim yScale = 100

            Dim buffer(batch) As Single

            Dim read As Integer

            Dim xPos = 0
            read = Reader.Read(buffer, 0, batch)
            While read = batch
                For n As Integer = 0 To read
                    max = Math.Max(Math.Abs(buffer(n)), max)
                Next

                Dim line As New Line
                line.X1 = xPos
                line.X2 = xPos
                line.Y1 = mid + (max * yScale)
                line.Y2 = mid - (max * yScale)
                line.Tag = Reader.CurrentTime

                line.StrokeThickness = 1
                line.Stroke = Brushes.DarkGray

                AddHandler line.MouseDown, AddressOf Line_MouseDown

                waveform.Children.Add(line)

                ' lines is a dictionary that holds all of the line information. nothing is bound to it, it just allows me to search against time code so I can highlight the line as the audio is playing' 
                If Not lines.ContainsKey(Reader.CurrentTime.Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & Reader.CurrentTime.Minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & Reader.CurrentTime.Seconds.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & Reader.CurrentTime.Milliseconds.ToString().PadLeft(3, "0").Substring(0, 1)) Then
                    lines.Add(Reader.CurrentTime.Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & Reader.CurrentTime.Minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & Reader.CurrentTime.Seconds.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & Reader.CurrentTime.Milliseconds.ToString().PadLeft(3, "0").Substring(0, 1), line)
                End If

                ' Draw a tall black line and show timecode every 10 seconds to make it easier to see where you are on the code '
                If Reader.CurrentTime.TotalSeconds > (seconds + 10) Then
                    seconds = Reader.CurrentTime.TotalSeconds
                    line = New Line
                    line.X1 = xPos
                    line.X2 = xPos
                    line.Y1 = mid + yScale
                    line.Y2 = mid - yScale

                    line.StrokeThickness = 1
                    line.Stroke = Brushes.Black
                    waveform.Children.Add(line)

                    Dim textblock As New TextBlock
                    textblock.Text = Reader.CurrentTime.Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & ":" & Reader.CurrentTime.Minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & ":" & Reader.CurrentTime.Seconds.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & "," & Reader.CurrentTime.Milliseconds.ToString().PadLeft(3, "0")
                    textblock.Foreground = Brushes.Black
                    Canvas.SetLeft(textblock, xPos)
                    Canvas.SetTop(textblock, yScale)
                    waveform.Children.Add(textblock)
                End If

                max = 0
                xPos += 1
                read = Reader.Read(buffer, 0, batch)
            End While
            waveform.Width = xPos
        End Using
```

ObservableCollection:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Public Class ocAudioSelection
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Private _Changed As Boolean
    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal Propertyname As String)
        On Error GoTo sError

        If Not Propertyname.Contains("Changed") Then
            Changed = True
        End If
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(Propertyname))

        Exit Sub
sError:
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    End Sub

    Public Property Changed() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Changed
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            If _Changed <> value Then
                _Changed = value
                OnPropertyChanged("Changed")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _startTime As String
    Private _endTime As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(startTime As String)
        _startTime = startTime
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(startTime As String, endTime As String)
        _startTime = startTime
        _endTime = endTime
    End Sub

    Public Property StartTime As String
        Get
            Return _startTime 
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If value <> _startTime Then 
                _startTime = value
                OnPropertyChanged("StartTime")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property EndTime As String
        Get
            Return _endTime 
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If value <> _endTime Then 
                _endTime = value 'TimeSpan.Parse()
                OnPropertyChanged("EndTime")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: You should not try to get this information from the view. It belongs to the view model instead.

Comment: It would help if you distilled this down to a very minimal example of what you're trying to accomplish, since there are lots of ways to solve your problem! Vaguely: I'd make a custom control capable of displaying waveforms and having Dependency Properties of start and end time and and waveform samples (byte[] array?). Inside the control, you know your layout dimensions and can Arrange children appropriately, as well as draw your lines using the graphics layer. Since everything is local, all you need to know is your own width, not where you live on the screen.

Comment: Alternatively! Are you aware of binding Converters (`{Binding Path=..., Converter=...)? You could potentially write your own converter to turn a TimeSpan into a pixel. Whatever you do, you need a mapping between time and pixels (forward and backward if you want to also convert screen coordinates to time).

Comment: My MVVM knowledge is a little shaky. still learning stuff. My one thought was to pass the lines dictionary to the observable collection, and then I could have it calculate the Left and Width based on that. But maybe it's just as easy to calculate the number of pixels based on time code. it's not like it has to be precise, just really close.